# Intellectual Property Rights When Moving University

Tags: career-path, professorship, europe, intellectual-property

I am considering moving institutions (from a one UK University to another), but I am concerned about what Intellectual Property (IP) rights my current institution may retain. Some of my PhD students, one of whom has been funded by my university directly, would move with me, or at least I would like them to. I am also unclear about the rights they/I would have to the research they have already done. Their projects would naturally remain similar, but I see no obvious commercial potential, and have no intention of trying to find some.

My questions are:

1. The University's policy is clear that they own all Intellectual Property I produce during my employment. I assume this can't apply to projects that have not got to the point of being protectable/tradeable but where one project begins and another ends is not always clear. Many of these projects naturally build on work I have published, or is in the process of being published. **How can I tell/establish what exactly they have rights to?**
2. How do I 'leave' them with what they own so that I can make a clean break.

Comment: I'm confused, it seems like you are employed? Isn't there nothing on this topic in your employment contract?

Comment: There is a policy, which states that all IP created whilst employed is owned by the University. However, the policy also makes it clear that I am expected to make them aware of anything that potentially commercializable. Given I don't think I have anything, and haven't made them aware of it, it's not clear where that leaves me. The policy is also very clear about my responsibilities as an employee, but not what happens if I am not. I will edit to clarify.

Comment: This sounds like the sort of thing that should be discussed with the department. You don't want problems years down the road when it turns out that research you have already started does have commercial value.

Comment: There are two reasons why asking these questions from eg your uni is much better idea than here: 1) details always depend on university AND often on negotiation, 2) details may depend on very specifics of your research - if you are an engineer you most probably have other problems than a mathematician.

Comment: My issue is that I would not want to alert my department to the fact that I am considering leaving and so was hoping to obtain some general advice.

Comment: Go consult a lawyer who does IP law. This is going to be very fact specific and contract specific.

Comment: 'The University's policy is clear that they own all Intellectual Property' Unusual for starters: most UK university employment contracts leave at least the copyright in "articles for publication" in the ownership of the individual authors.

Answer (score 1):

In general you should be fine:

- Your research is published, so everyone (including you) can build upon it.
- You do not have any patents (which would remain at the university)

The only thing might be software written at your institution or hardware built during your work. Those remain at the university as long as you do not agree on otherwise. But usually, one becomes smarter over time so this might be a good point in time to re-implement some stuff...

On the other hand, your work might be worthless for your university when you are not there - e.g. no one will digg into foreign research code... So you should have a good position for negotiations.

Comment: You seem to be giving a legal opinion. I don't think that is proper here. Are you a qualified UK lawyer?

Comment: @Buffy: There is nothing definite in the answer (everything has *should*s, *might*s, and similar). Also, the entire concept of giving opinion on legal questions being illegal is limited to the US, as far as I know, and even there this is probably far from problematic. (If not, please cite a respective law that says otherwise.)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft, I don't claim it is illegal, just unwise. If the advice is taken and turns out to be wrong, the OP will be the one that suffers, not the person giving the bad advice.

Comment: @Buffy: Can you tell me one statement of which you think it might be unvalid? And as Wrzlprmft already noted: There are enough *should* in the text to indicate that the real situation might be different since we do not know the specifics of this university and the work involved. I'm sure the OP can put the answer in the right context and will ask a lawyer if needed.

Comment: You leave the impression that there are few issues. I disagree. The OP says the university claims rights. Depending on the level of insistence they have it could be a serious issue. Work in progress? Courseware? Lab procedures? There are a lot of things potentially other than already published papers, patents, and software. My first line would be "In general, you need to know more, both from the university and their lawyers." and NOT, "you should be fine."

Comment: I think the point Buffy is making is that if you wish to offer an opinion that a particular course of action "should be fine" then it would be useful to know if you are a lawyer yourself, and what is the legal basis for the asserted opinion.  I don't think it's incumbent on Buffy to point out errors in the assertion --- he just wants to know if there is any legal training/experience/reasoning behind those assertions.

Answer (score 1):

Read the contracts and policies.  If the existing contracts and policies are not answering your questions, then this is something you cannot resolve.  It is up to the universities to work out between them how to divide intellectual property.

If the intellectual property is very valuable, the lawyers of the two universities will negotiate a deal.  Nobody will want to license something if the owner of the rights is uncertain.  As a result, the universities will be motivated to cooperate.  Arranging this is not the author/inventor's responsibility.

If the intellectual property is not valuable, then so long as you are honest and open about what is going on I doubt you will have any problems.

Comment: Beware that the contracts and policies may contridict each other and in the case of the policies, themselves. It may need a lawyer to work out what the actual grant is in that case if you are unwilling to talk to the university.

Answer (score -4):

I think regarding publications, as soon as you include the affiliation of the old uni on publications whose work has started during your employment there it should be fine.
If there are patents involved things might get more complicated.

What other issues were you thinking about?

Comment: I wonder, can the people who voted negative in this answer please explain what is wrong with what is stated here?